# Pigenhole principle: Prove or disprove that one of the buses will have $14$ empty seats.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Eight school buses are used to take $375$ students to an exhibition center. Each school bus has $60$ seats. Prove or disprove that one of the buses will have $14$ empty seats.

Comment: It doesn't have to be.  Busses 1-6 could be completely full. Bus 7 could have 15 students and 45 empty seats.  The 8 bus could have no students (but the driver had a really good union representative).  I think you meant at least 14 empty seats which considering there are 105 empty seats distributed over 8 buses, is pretty obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In total the buses will have $480-375=105$ empty seats.

If each bus has less than 14 empty seats, then there can be a maximum of 13 x 8 = 104 empty seats.

But there are 105 empty seats. Therefore, by the Pigeonhole Principle, at least one bus must have at least 14 empty seats. Also waste of buses.